# Identity Server 4 Auth Grpc with Bearer Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, identityserver4

please help me.

I have the IdentityCenter app, in which I configured IS4.

```
        builder.Services
            .AddIdentityServer()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
            .AddConfigurationStore<ISConfigurationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                    b.UseNpgsql(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore<ISOperationalDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                    b.UseNpgsql(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            })
            .AddProfileService<SetUserDataToTokenService>();
```

In the same application, I have a Grpc server

```
        builder.Services.AddGrpc(options =>
        {
            options.Interceptors.Add<LoggingGrpcServerInterceptor>();
        });
```

```
app.MapGrpcService<UserInfoService>();
```

```
[Authorize]
internal class UserInfoService : UserInfo.UserInfoBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public UserInfoService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public override async Task<GetUserByIdResponseProto> GetUserData(GetUserByIdRequestProto request,
        ServerCallContext context)
    {
        
    }
}
```

From another app, I'm trying to send a request using the Bearer token

```
var headers = new Metadata
        {
            { "Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOi" }
            // { "Cookie", ".AspNetCore.Culture=c%3De" }
        };
```

The problem is that when a request is received in the Grpc Server, which is located in the IdentityCenter application, it is not possible to authorize the request using the Bearer token.
When I send a request with a `Cookie`, the request is authorized correctly.
how do I configure IS4 so that the IdentityCenter application can authorize requests not only with the `Cookie`, but also with the Bearer token.

Comment: You use the AddJwtBearer handler to accept tokens

Comment: No, i use IS4, by default it uses cookies for authorization. how can I make it use the JWT Beare token too?